# Sending function pointer with arguments with it and then add additional arguments while invoking

Tags: python

I have a map which says maps a string to a function like :

```
validator = {'first_name' : validate_str,
             'last_name' : validate_str,
             'phone' : validate_phone }
```

I need to call the corresponding validate function based on the type of value I have in the map that will be fed to me as input for e.g.

```
for name in elements:
    # Validate the value of this name in the input map using the function
    # input is the map that has the value for each of these fields
    # elements is a list of all fields used to loop through one input at a time
    if validator[name]( input[name] ) is False:
        # Throw validation error
    else:
        # Do something else
```

This works fine unless for this scenario I am not sure if it can be done:

The validate_str also checks if a given string is of desired max length.

```
def validate_str(str, max-len):
    # Throw error if len(str) > max-len
```

The max-len can differ based on the string, so I need to call validate_str for first_name with say 64 characters and last name with 256 characters.

I can use a different map to say that this field has this max_len, but is it possible for the validator map to have pointer to the validate_str function with the max-len argument preset based on the field?

something like:

```
validator = {'first_name' : validate_str(max-len=64),
             'last_name' : validate_str(max-len=256),
             'phone' : validate_phone }
```

then call it for validation like:

```
if validator[name]( str=input[name] ) is False:
    # The appropriate value for max-len goes with the function call and just the
    # str is appended to the argument list while invoking.
```

This makes life easier so that we need not then remember again what fields will have the max-len sent along with it.

Comment: possible typos: By `validate` do you mean `validator`? What is `elements`? It seems to be a list of strings like `first_name`, `last_name`, or a dictionary.

Comment: Corrected the mistakes.. Thanks for pointing it out..

Comment: No problem. You might benefit from making `elements` a dictionary `data = {'first_name':'Bob', 'last_name':'Bobley', 'phone':1234567890}` and doing `for field,value in data.items(): if not validator[field](value):...`. Reads much more cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use lambda to create a function of one argument (the string being validated) but has the length defined within in:

```
{'first-name':lambda x: validate-str( x, 64 ), ...
```

Comment: Works like a champ.. Kudos to you :-)

Comment: This is one of the two answers the OP was looking for. For reference, this is using a lambda to curry a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

The answer you specifically asked for is how to curry it (which Scott Hunter answered).

Another way is to use a function factory ("higher-order function") to return a function which captures the custom parameters in a closure, such as:

```
def makeStringValidator(maxLength=64):
    def validator(string):
        return len(string)<maxLength
    return validator
```

---

In general however, restricting yourself to this system prevents you from having "cross-cutting" validation between fields. For example, if you had fields `birthday_day, birthday_month, birthday_year` as separate fields, you could individually verify that say each day was either 30 or 31, but wouldn't know the month in order to determine which (also leap days in February).

I however personally use this system from time to time. You can just supplement your current system with something more complicated later, if such needs arise.